# Flask.test_client().post and JSON encoding

Tags: python, json, testing, flask

I am writing test cases for JSON endpoints in a Flask app.

```
import unittest
from flask import json
from app import create_app


class TestFooBar(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app('testing')
        self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()

    def test_ham(self):
        resp = self.client.post('/endpoint',
                                headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                                data=json.dumps({'foo': 2,
                                                 'bar': 3}))
        assert resp.status_code == 200

    def test_eggs(self):
        resp = self.client.post('/endpoint', data={'foo': 5,
                                                   'bar': 7})
        assert resp.status_code == 200

    def test_ham_and_eggs(self):
        with self.app.test_client() as self.client:
            self.test_ham()
            self.test_eggs()
```

Just to understand what's happening, do both ways of sending a `POST` message in the code above make sense? In particular, am I double-JSON encoding in the first case?

Or, briefly, what is the difference between `test_ham` and `test_eggs`? Is there any?

Comment: Please stick to **one question per post**. `json.dump()` and `json.dumps()` are documented clearly in the [module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), one writes the result to a file, the other returns the encoded JSON data to the caller.

Comment: The `get_json()` warning indicates you are using `request.json` somewhere in your Flask app, and the warning tells you to use `request.get_json()` instead. See [How to get POSTed json in Flask?](//stackoverflow.com/a/20001283)

Comment: If you want to see where you are using `request.json`, you can turn the warning into an exception by running Flask with `PYTHONWARNINGS=error`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not double-encoding JSON, no, because `data` doesn't encode anything to JSON. `test_ham` posts JSON, `test_eggs` does not.

Starting from Flask 1.0, the Flask test client supports posting JSON directly, via the `json` keyword argument, use it to cut down on boilerplate code here:

```
def test_ham(self):
    resp = self.client.post('/endpoint', json={'foo': 2, 'bar': 3})
    assert resp.status_code == 200
```

See the [*Testing JSON APIs* section](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/testing/#testing-json-apis) of the Flask *Testing* documentation chapter:

> Passing the `json` argument in the test client methods sets the request data to the JSON-serialized object and sets the content type to `application/json`.

Passing a dictionary to `data` produces a different kind of request, a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded request just like a `<form method="POST" ...>` form would produce from your browser, and the `foo` and `bar` values would have to be accessed via the [`request.form` object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.form). Do not use it when posting JSON is needed.